# Push UIViewController to UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have `UITabBarController`, which has four tabs. When moving from another `UIViewController` to one of the view in `UITabBarController`, bottom Tab Bar item is not appearing and also there is  space at the top and bottom of the screen. How can I avoid that. I am using storyboard.

Here is the code I am using, while moving from `UIViewController` to `UITabBarController`:

```
 HomePage *mvc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomePage"];
[self presentViewController:mvc animated:YES completion:nil];
    mvc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
```

Comment: This Homepage is your UITabBarcontroller???
are you using iPhone5?

Comment: can you paste screenshot of your Storyboard?

Comment: @Deepak, Yes HomePage is My UITabBarcontroller and it has four tabs

Comment: Bro as you are adding UITabBar programmatically , you should decrease height of your 4 controllers so that when they are added in TabBar their top bar is visible, try this and let me know.

Comment: that's great. keep good going

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, if you're moving to a `UIViewController` in `UITabBarController` it will be messed up. What you need to do is move to the `UITabBarController` and set it with the correct UIViewControllers with `setViewControllers:animated:`

So set a segue to the `UITabBarController` and use `setViewControllers:animated:` and put your UIViewController in the array as parameter to `setViewControllers:animated:`.

Answer (score 4):

Is the space the only problem that you have?

1.) Make sure that the UIViewController in storyboard/ib has the same imitated UIItems (Bottom Bar, Navigation Bar, Status Bar) that are displayed on runtime. 
Doing so you can fully utilize the available space. Plus the associated view will have the correct size.

2.) Have an eye on the autolayout option and settings. Depending on what you do in detail you can end up with what you describe or with a view that smoothly fits into a larger or smaller superview - as far as possible.